# How to solve Assigment problem on SPOJ?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, bit-manipulation

Problem Link - [Assign](https://www.spoj.com/problems/ASSIGN/) .This problem is known as assignment problem.

I read few solutions  [Here is one](https://github.com/fazlulkabir94/spoj-problem-solution/blob/master/ASSIGN%20-%20Assignments.cpp)   and they are trying to solve it using Bit-masking and DP .I tried and thought hard to understand how to solve it but i was unsuccessful ..

Comment: We require questions to be self-contained, so that the problem statement can be  understood without having to follow an external link, and so that the question will remain understandable even if the link stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us enumerate the students $s_1, \dots, v_n$. Let $A$ be the set of students and $B$ the set of subjects. Moreover, let $S_i$ be the set of subjects the student $s_i$ likes. The dynamic programming table will be $C\left(A, 2^B\right)$, where $C(s_i, S)$ says in how many ways we can assign the subjects in $S$ to the first $i$ students. Note that if $|S| \neq i$ we have $C(s_i, S) = 0$.

The recursive function is given by the formula $$C(s_i, S_i) = \sum_{p \in S \bigcap S_i} C(s_{i-1}, S\setminus {p}).$$

To implement the solution you need a loop over all the students and for each student iterate over all possible bit masks. For the student $i$ ignore all bitmasks with number of ones not equal to $i$. Now use the formula above to compute the value for each student and bitmask based on the values of previous students.

Notes:

- Checking if $M$ contains $k$ by $M \& (1<<k)$
- Adding subject $k$ to bitmask $M$ by $M = M | (1 << k)$
- Removing subject $k$ from bitmask $M$ by $M = M \& (((1<<n) - 1) - (1<<k))$.